# How to pass variable from the google.maps.InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, google-maps

I'm trying to transfer variable from the google.maps.InfoWindow:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<a href="#pinDetails?0?'+pin[i][2]+'">'+pin[i][2]+'</a>',
});
```

from the client site there is a full link at the html:

```
<a href="#pinDetails?0?SWA-ER-002">SWA-ER-002</a>
```

but I can receive only the part before the question mark of the link.

If I check the `linkwindow.location.href` I see only:

`index.html#pinDetails` but not `index.html#pinDetails?0?SWA-ER-002`

How can I transfer the data from the *google.maps.InfoWindow*?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`?` is a reserved url character. Try replacing `?` with `|`
so example

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<a href="#pinDetails|0|'+pin[i][2]+'">'+pin[i][2]+'</a>',
});
```

which would show up as

```
<a href="#pinDetails|0|SWA-ER-002">SWA-ER-002</a>
```

Comment: Of course I've tried the different characters, but the event handler can't recognize it:

`$(document).on("pageshow", "#pinDetails", function(){`

the same code work with other map API, but don't work with a google map API

Comment: can you check this codepen? maybe modify it to show me an example of what you are trying to achieve?
http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/wGyapK

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Rohit Agre, the problem has been solved. I've changed the event handler from `$(document).on("pageshow", "#pinDetails", function()` to `$(document).on("click", "#details", function()`